# Stop animation on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking around **SO** and couldn't really find a good concrete answer. My problem is that when the `.mouseenter(function(){ })` is fired and the `.mouseleave(function(){ })` is fired right after it completes both animation, instead I want the `.mouseleave(function(){ })` to stop the `.mouseenter(function(){ })` from finishing it's animation.

Here' a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nyEZ/1/) of how I currently have it.

**HtML:**

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-align">

  </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -170px;
}

#header #header-align {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted #000;  
  margin: 0 auto 0;   
}
```

**jQuery**

```
​$("#header").mouseenter(function(){

  $(this).animate({ top: -20 }, {
    duration: 'slow',
    easing: 'easeOutBack'
  })

});

$("#header").mouseleave(function(){

  $(this).animate({ top: -170 }, {
     duration: 'slow',
     easing: 'easeOutBack'
  })

});
```

I was thinking something like `bind(function(){ })` or something like `.stopPropagation()` but couldn't find a good answer

Comment: `.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )` -> [**DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try adding in a `.stop()`?

```
$(this).stop().animate({ top: -170 }, {
     duration: 'slow',
     easing: 'easeOutBack'
  })
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/JWurE/)

You may also consider using `.hover()`.

```
​$("#header").hover(function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ top: -20 }, {
    duration: 'slow',
    easing: 'easeOutBack'
  })
},
function(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ top: -170 }, {
     duration: 'slow',
     easing: 'easeOutBack'
  })
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/JWurE/). I would also add a `.stop()` before the `.mouseenter()`.